# Lightning Web Component | navigator.geolocation not able to assign value to track variable

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, geolocation

I am trying to get the current location coordinates using `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` inside a Lightning Web Component.

**Expected :**

I am getting the coordinates correctly in the `position.coords.latitude` and `position.coords.longitude`
But I am not able to assign the value to any track variable. (`strLatitude` is a track variable)

**Code Snippet:**

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    function(position) {
        console.log(position.coords.latitude); **//This console shows value**
        this.strLatitude = position.coords.latitude;
        console.log(this.strLatitude); **//This console doesnt shows value**
    }, function(e){            
        console.log(e.message);        
    }, {            
        enableHighAccuracy: true        
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is set incorrectly because it's a callback. Use arrow functions instead:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  (position) => {
    console.log(position.coords.latitude);
    this.strLatitude = position.coords.latitude;
    console.log(this.strLatitude);
  },
  (e) => {
    this.strError = e.message;
  },
  {
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
  }
);
```

Or, you can bind to the component controller to make sure that `this` is what you expect it to be:

```
  connectedCallback() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      function (position) {
        console.log(position.coords.latitude);
        this.strLatitude = position.coords.latitude;
        console.log(this.strLatitude);
      }.bind(this),
      function (e) {
        console.log(e.message);
      }.bind(this),
      {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox. Its working. Learned something new as well.